# Compressing Windows 10 system folders

Tags: windows-10, filesystems, operating-systems, restrictions

When I was stuck with Windows XP I was able to compress all harddrive folders into WinRAR files.

I don't know if my ability to do that had to do with less restrictions within XP or that I had multiple installations of XP where the restrictions wouldn't be inforced after jumping between partitions/operating systems.

Now, I tried to do the same thing with my multiple partitions/Windows 10 installations and even after trying to edit the permissions to be used by my account/profile on a specific system folder, for example the C:/Users folder.

What am I missing?

Comment: Do you mean to *compress the folder in use*, or to *create a compressed archive of its data for backup*? The former can only work if all data on the disk is compressed.

Comment: How are your two examples any different? Yes, folder/files are in use and with those I want to create a zip/rar file. But are you saying that I only need to compress the partition each time I want to compress those system folders? I don't need to bother with permissions/restrictions?

Comment: The difference: to *compress* a file means to make the existing file smaller. To make a *compressed archive* (AKA "to zip a file") is *not* to compress that file *in situ*, but to create a *new*, compressed, file, which contains the untouched old. It's the difference between shrinking a wool sweater in a hot wash, and making a copy of the sweater with finer yarn.

Comment: Good explanation of the difference... Thank you! So, if I just want to clone the original files/folders then what is the best way of doing that? I tried using the scheduler under Windows to create a copy with the shadow copy service but even with this guide it does not want to even start: https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.minitool.com/amp/backup-tips/shadow-copy-windows-10-017.html

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to create a backup file with all system information, use any of the free and paid backup utilities, such as [Macrium Reflect Free](https://www.macrium.com/reflectfree) or an [alternative](https://alternativeto.net/software/macrium-reflect/). Not only will this save required files in Windows, but in other locations, such as ProgramData and Users.

[image: Macrium Reflect to make system backup]

You can also make an image of the whole disk.

The reason the folders are locked to you, the user, is that the files are in active use, being written to and read from by the system. To get around this while the OS is running, imaging applications use the [Volume Shadow Copy Service](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/file-server/volume-shadow-copy-service), which creates a self-consistent snapshot of the HDD that can be viewed or copied. If you have the burning desire to access one of these locked folders to view the file or to to make a compressed archive, boot from another OS on external media, e.g. Windows PE (WinPE, [Windows Preinstallation Environment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Preinstallation_Environment)), which Reflect uses to make a rescue disk, or a live Linux USB. You can also *browse* the folder in the image file made by backup software -- just be sure to [*Enable access to restricted folders*](https://knowledgebase.macrium.com/display/KNOW72/Browsing+Macrium+Reflect+images+and+backups+in+Windows+Explorer).

Comment: I'm so used to doing it my way that I haven't looked for software that does it for me. The reason you mention to why folders are in their locked state, shouldn't that disappear once I jump to another partition that uses their own copy of the folder on it's own partition?

Comment: How do you "jump to another partition"? How does another partition have an active copy of a Windows system folder??

Comment: During the Windows 10 installation process I created three partitions... The first for the Backup process for the other two, second for my Development tasks and third for my Gaming collection... How? I do not know and understand but I get that issue with the file/folder is unaccessible, like if I'm on the active partition and trying to create a compressed file...